# How to create a Cabal Sandbox

Tags: haskell, virtualenv, sandbox, cabal

I want to build an environment for tutorial programs for Haskell, as I want to try and learn the language. So I read about Cabal and already have it on my machine, because I updated pandoc sometimes. I followed some [tutorials](http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-20-Cabal-sandbox.html), which state that you should run:

```
$ cabal sandbox init
$ cabal install --only-dependencies
$ cabal build
```

To have the environment set up. However, if I try so, I receive the following message:

```
$ cabal sandbox init
Writing a default package environment file to
/home/xiaolong/development/Haskell/cabal.sandbox.config
Using an existing sandbox located at
/home/xiaolong/development/Haskell/.cabal-sandbox
```

(Output of `ls` command)

```
$ ls
cabal.sandbox.config
```

And then:

```
$ cabal install --only-dependencies
cabal: Error reading local package.
Couldn't find .cabal file in: .
```

Huh? Suddenly there needs to be a `.cabal` file? This is puzzling to me. What steps do I need to take to get an environment, in which I can simply install packages and then use that environment to run code of any tutorials I choose?

[This](http://katychuang.com/cabal-guide/) is another tutorial suggesting the described workflow. Something is there I am missing.

(I am under the impression, that cabal sandboxes are comparable to python virtualenvs, being useful in the way, that one doesn't need to install packages system-wide, but can instead install them in a directory and then use that environment to run programs.)

Comment: You need to have a cabal file inside it. You can generate one by issuing `cabal init` command and following the steps. You can list out your package dependencies in the field named `build-depends` on the cabal file.

Comment: @Sibi But I ran the `cabal sandbox init` already. Is that not the same as `cabal init`? The steps on that tutorial don't mention `cabal init` - I'll try it! Ha, that worked! Could you make this an answer?

Comment: You can install individual packages with `cabal --require-sandbox install <pkg-name>` into the sandbox (assuming you are in the correct dir). You can then access these without a cabal file using `cabal --require-sandbox repl`. The `--require-sandbox` part might not always be needed, but if you don't have a .cabal file, it's your safest bet. Obviously `--dependencies` *cannot* work without a .cabal file - which dependencies should it look for? I think this requires a fairly recent version of cabal. You don't *need* a .cabal file - it is just much easier to have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a cabal file inside it which describes your project's name, package dependencies, license etc. A cabal file can be generated using `cabal init` which is followed by a series of question you have to answer.

Once the initial cabal configuration file is created, you can go inside the package directory and create sandbox inside it using the commands you have described above.

You may be also interested in [Stack](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README.html) which is another alternate (better, if you would ask me :)) tool for developing Haskell projects.